# How do I use XSL:if with classes?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's a basic example of what I'd like to do today:

```
IF CLASS=.TEST Show THIS content
```

I'm not to clear on all of the variables I can place within: `< xsl:if test="{HERE}" >`

*Note: I can manipulate the content by using Boolean: `< xsl:if test="price>2" >` but mathematical equations won't really help me for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: what do you mean with classes? what CLASS is for you? Are you able to provide an example of XML upon which you'd like to perform your test?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you could target a class or ID in the test=""... ie: `<xsl:if test="{CLASS=SOMECLASSNAMEHERE}">`

Comment: _but mathematical equations won't really help me for what I'm trying to accomplish_ ...so what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Empo, I was just trying to gain a better understanding to what "expressions" I could use within `<xsl:if test="{HERE}">` If it doesn't make sense, I'll read up, and ask again if need be.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to check our w3schools here: http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/el_if.asp.

In your scenario you might be better with

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="test1">output1</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="test2">output2</xsl:when>
    ...
    <xsl:otherwise>some error or other</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Does anyone recommend a phrase I can google to help me get a better understanding about what types of "expressions" I can use in the (test="") attribute?

Comment: Try "XPath specification" or "XPath tutorial", depending whether you want the accurate formal spec or someone's attempt at an idiot's guide to it.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases you don't need to use a conditional XSLT instruction such as `<xsl:if>`.

**It is better to use pattern matching**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@class='someValue']">
  <!-- Necessary processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Just to clarify "In many cases...".  Template matching works when the output document order matches the source document order.  If the order is different for the output document, then the conditional XSLT may be used.

Comment: @bob.faist: The statement: "Template matching works when the output document order matches the source document order" is incorrect. Template matching never "works" by itself. It is always the <xsl:apply-templates> instructions that cause a template to be selected for processing a specific node. Your statements is true if the only <xsl:apply-templates> instructions are in the built-in templates, or if the explicit <xsl:apply-templates> in the code don't have a select attribute. Using the select attribute or an <xsl:sort> child, the results of processing can be ordered in many different ways